# dladm show-phys shows speed 0

Tags: networking, solaris

we have a M6-32 and I need to know which speed is running each interface. When I issue the dladm show-phys I have this strange behaviour:

```
LINK              MEDIA                STATE      SPEED  DUPLEX    DEVICE 
eserc_1           Ethernet             up         0      unknown   vnet1 
eserc_0           Ethernet             up         0      unknown   vnet0 
bkp1              Ethernet             up         0      unknown   vnet2 
bkp0              Ethernet             up         0      unknown   vnet3
```

the SPEED field is 0, I cannot understand why. I don't know if it matters that all this NICs are under a relative IPMP group. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you plumbed the interfaces?

Comment: Yes, as you can see the STATE is up.

Comment: Are you running `dladm` as root?

Comment: Yes, I am indeed.

Comment: Are you running in an LDOM?

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet worked on a M6 system, but I suspect you're running in a LDOM or an M6's hardware domain.  If so, perhaps the interfaces aren't configured at the domain level?

What do the ipadm cmds show?
`ipadm show-if; ipadm show-addr`